# Can't talk to merchant to buy Gwent card?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

From what I can tell, the Heavy Zerrikanian Fire Scorpion card is only available from a merchant in Lindenvale [(link here)](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Heavy+Zerrikanian+Fire+Scorpion+(Gwent+Card)). I found the guy, that's not the problem. But I can't talk to him. The prompt never even pops up. This is the guy (not my picture though). Anyone have a solution to this issue?

[image: Lindenvale merchant]

Comment: According to this [link](http://www.primagames.com/games/witcher-3/tips/most-powerful-gwent-cards-witcher-3-wild-hunt), that card is in Midcopse.

Comment: It seems that the PS4 cannot handle to load every resource etc at the same time.. if you ported there, you've to wait a while before you'are able to talk to the merchant

Comment: I didn't. Rode from Crow's Perch (started a new game+ and hadn't discovered it yet). Also, the most I've seen this delay is about 5 seconds (almost always less), not 5 minutes. But I suppose I'll just try to reload an earlier save, try again, and wait longer.

Comment: I had that problem with a blacksmith... I meditated for 1 hour and tried again. And then it worked.

Comment: I don't recall trying that, I think I just stood around for a while. I'll have to give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to combine a couple methods before I was able to talk to the merchant. I'm guessing I just had an extra buggy game, since I talked to a couple people who didn't have an issue with the same merchant. Basically, I saved before going to him, then meditating for a little bit, and finally just decided to run around for a minute or so and when I came back, I could talk to him.

I can also confirm this is where the Heavy Zerrikanian Fire Scorpion card is.